# Behat on Windows - taking screenshots

Tags: php, bdd, behat, mink

I've got several Behat tests that take screenshots using something similar to this:

```
$driver->getWebDriverSession()->screenshot();
```

Does anyone know of a Behat plugin or extension that can compare two screenshots?
And it must work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a pdiff extension: for windows it probably looks like this: http://seleniumrecipes.com/content/using-perceptual-difference-pdiff-tool

Screenshots are definitely not "only taken on failure" - you can certainly take a baseline set of screenshots and use a tool like https://github.com/jadu/BehatPerceptualDiffExtension to fail a test if the resultant perceptual diff deviates (i.e. if a css change overreached in unexpected ways).

This fork (https://github.com/ksenzee/BehatPerceptualDiffExtension/commits/master) of the PerceptualDiffExtention adds a concept of diff masks - i.e. regions that you would want to ignore - for example if you had some sort of slideshow, the screenshot may show a fail because the random starting slide is different.

Additionally the Author recently gave a talk on using perceptual diffs with Behat: http://2014.pnwdrupalsummit.org/pacific-nw-drupal-summit-2014/sessions/deploying-confidence-automated-visual-regression-and so there are some slides you could use as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Behat for awhile now and it's certainly isn't as popular as it should be. There's not that many popular plugins from any team other than Behat's, and there's definitely no well-known / well-supported plugin for Behat to compare images. In fact that would be true for PHP as well, except for the GD and Imagic, which have a much broader scope.

Besides, the logic isn't very clear what and how you'd compare. Screenshots are normally taken on failure. Comparing two screenshots of failed tests doesn't make much sense, only comparing screenshots of failed tests against screenshots of relevant tests that passed before. The questions is then where and how would you get those valid screenshots, and the whole chain of other questions coming from here.

That sounds like a very specific challenge and I'm certain only a limited group of users would need something like that, probably with a lot of logic unique and specific to their case. On another hand, implementing basic image comparison in PHP isn't that difficult, given you have the basic skills working with graphics in PHP.

One thing that comes to mind is `Imagick::compareImages`, see the official [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compareimages.php). There also seem to be plenty of blog posts, like [this](http://www.robert-lerner.com/code/image-compare) one or [this](http://www.intelliot.com/2008/03/sorted-directory-listing-image-resizing-comparison-and-similarity-in-php/) one, which show different ways of doing that.